# Probability & Statistics: Determining a threshold for count number

Tags: probability, statistics

Good day,

I am trying to work out a threshold for a certain statistical problem. I apologize that the title is so unclear, I personally couldn't think of a more specific way to address this problem without making it a story.

To be honest, I don't know how to clearly pose my question at all, so I'll begin by trying to explain the setup and see if something can be done from there.

Alright, so the situation is as follows. I have a certain system, that has two different properties: N and M. N has three different states, N1, N2 and N3. M has two different states, M1 and M2. They are related in the following way:

$\displaystyle P \left({M_1 \mid N_1}\right) = 1$

$\displaystyle P \left({M_1 \mid N_2}\right) = 0.5$

$\displaystyle P \left({M_1 \mid N_3}\right) = 0$

And it is of course the opposite for M2.

Now, I have a 'problem': I want to know what N is (so N1 or N2 or N3), but I cannot directly determine this. What I can do however, is find out what state M is in. But, to make things a little more intricate, I can't do so perfectly.

So, how shall I put this, I have a certain fidelity with which I determine the state of M. Lets call this F. So if I measure M, I find out the correct state with probability F.

$\displaystyle P \left({measuring M_1 \mid M_1}\right) = F$

$\displaystyle P \left({measuring M_2 \mid M_2}\right) = F$

Now, this thus means that if I do my measurement only once, I won't really know how correct I am. I thus do this N times. To make it easier, if I record M1 I write down a 1, and if I record M2 I write down a 0.

What I am now interested in, is what I can say about state N, after measuring state M with fidelity F N times.

More directly; what kind of threshold should I impose on my average measurement of M, or on the number of times I measure M = M1, in order to discern between the three states of N?

I personally don't know where to begin with this, as whatever I do I inevitably get stuck in some sort of circle in my head. I am having a lot of trouble finding the clarity to tackle this problem step by step. I would therefore like to ask you if you can help guide me towards solving this.

If anything is unclear (which it definitely might), please comment!

Edit: I forgot to say, but it seems to me as if a binomial distribution is certainly related to this, as I am measuring M1 and M2 with certain probabilities.

Comment: Alright, so I had an idea. If N = N1, then M = M1 with probability 1. So if I perform N measurements, the chance of obtaining k M1 results (which I called a '1') is given by the binomial distribution with p = F.

Comment: Hm yes, maybe that makes sense. There would be three binomial distributions:
If N = N1, then the number of M1 measurements (call it k) would be distributed as binom(k,N,F)
If N = N2, then as binom(k,N,0.5F)
If N = N3, then as binom(k,N,1-F)
This seems to make sense. But then for a threshold.. Maybe take the points where they intersect? How could I justify that?

Comment: There are questions of variability and independence: can the measurement of $M$ change each time it is measured?.  If $N=N_2$, can the value of $M$ change each time it is measured?  Can the value of $N$ change each time $M$ is measured?  If values can change, are they independent of previous values?  Do you have any prior idea how likely $N_1$,$N_2$,$N_3$ are.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. Yes, the value of N can change every time a measurement is performed, and in principle (but not surely) N1 N2 and N3 are equally likely. 
If N = N2, then M is M1 50% of the time, and M2 50% of the time. So it can change every time it is measured. And in principle these are indeed independent.
Oh, and indeed, measuring M can change N, but only from N1 to N2, from N3 to N2 or from N2 to N1 or N3.

Answer (score 0):

- If $N=N_1$ the probability of seeing $M_1$ is $F$
- If $N=N_2$ the probability of seeing $M_1$ is $\frac12$
- If $N=N_3$ the probability of seeing $M_1$ is $1-F$

You have said that in principle $N_1,N_2,N_3$ are equally likely.  So

- If you see $M_1$ the probability of $N=N_1$ is $\frac{\frac13 F}{\frac13 F + \frac13 \times \frac12 +  \frac13 (1-F)} = \frac23 F$
- If you see $M_1$ the probability of $N=N_2$ is $\frac13$
- If you see $M_1$ the probability of $N=N_3$ is $\frac23 (1-F)$

and similarly

- If you see $M_2$ the probability of $N=N_1$ is $\frac23 (1-F)$
- If you see $M_2$ the probability of $N=N_2$ is $\frac13$
- If you see $M_2$ the probability of $N=N_3$ is $\frac23 F$

Since $N$ may change each time you take a measurement of $M$, you may not be able to do much better than this.